# Installing JDK 1.7 on CentOS

Tags: centos, centos5, java

I'm trying to install JDK 1.7 on CentOS on my server. I've downloaded  java_ee_sdk-6u3-jdk7-linux-x64.sh from Oracle website. Looks like it requires graphic interface, which I don't have on remote server. I haven't found any RPMs on Oracle website. yum install java installed jdk 1.6, but I need 1.7

Comment: Does not it show a CLI-based menu?

Comment: it shows this: ./java_ee_sdk-6u3-jdk7-linux-x64.sh
This program requires DISPLAY environment variable to be set.
Please re-run after assigning an appropriate value to DISPLAY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the `jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz` or `jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz` and simply uncompress one of those archives.
It is enough to install a JDK (**[Java SE Development Kit 7 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u3-download-1501626.html)**)

And it is quite different from installing a [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 6 SDK Update 3 (with JDK 7)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7-downloads-439818.html), from the [Java EE 6 SDK Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) (which, indeed, might require a GUI).

Comment: after I uninstalled jdk why does yum asks for openjdk? I removed openjdk.

Comment: @kinkajou I don't know. I know jdk and openjdk are two different product, only the second one can be installed without having to accept a license first.

Comment: I have installed oracle jdk already but yum stills asks for openjdk.

Comment: yum should ask because of another product which depends on it, I suppose.

Comment: thank you I got it may be cassandra2 requires openjdk but i already have oracle jdk!

Answer (score 1):

If I look at the download page, there is an rpm for x86 and x64

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u3-download-1501626.html